# Generate `CREATE TABLE...` statement from an sqlboiler model

Tags: go, sqlboiler

Is it possible to generate a create statement (`CREATE TABLE...`) from a built [SQLBoiler](https://github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler) model?

```golang
// Node is an object representing the database table.
type Node struct {
    ID      int64       `boil:"id" json:"id" toml:"id" yaml:"id"`
    Address null.String `boil:"address" json:"address,omitempty" toml:"address" yaml:"address,omitempty"`

    R *nodeR `boil:"-" json:"-" toml:"-" yaml:"-"`
    L nodeL  `boil:"-" json:"-" toml:"-" yaml:"-"`
}
```

Comment: as you can see on repo they said: It is a "database-first" ORM as opposed to "code-first" (like gorm/gorp). That means you must first create your database schema.

Comment: Where did you get the sqlboiler struct from? Sqlboiler created the struct by reading the DB schema of a DB.